# Javascript : evaluate delta between UTC and Central Europe Time

Tags: node.js, datetime, google-cloud-functions, timezone-offset

I have a server app in Firebase cloud function with webhooks that receive data from a third party API.
In those data, I have times expressed in HH:mm local time (Central Europe Time).
I need to store them in Firestore as a timestamp UTC.

I tried this:

```
         //Evaluate offset between CET and UTC
        const dAujourdhui = new Date(); //07/03/2019 10:39 (UTC)
        const nHeureUTC = dAujourdhui.getUTCHours(); //10
        const nHeureLocal = dAujourdhui.getHours();  //10
        const timeZoneOffset = nHeureUTC - nHeureLocal //0!

         // Build a timestamp based on today's date and received time
        const currentDateString = dateFormat(dAujourdhui, "yyyy-mm-dd");
        var estimatedDateTimeOfArrival = new Date(`${currentDateString} ${timeReceivedFrom3rdPartyAPI}`);

         // Add offset to hours
        const utcHour = estimatedDateTimeOfArrival.getUTCHours()
        estimatedDateTimeOfArrival.setHours(utcHour + timeZoneOffset)

        // Save to firestore
        ...
```

As you can see, I'm not able to evaluate the offset between CET and UTC as the code is run in a server set in UTC.

Any idea on how to solve it ?

Comment: What *exactly* do you receive? Please provide an example.  Also, you have a `dateFormat` function - is that coming from a library? Which one?  Lastly, when you save to firestore at the end, what are you saving? Do you pass a `Date` object or a string in a particular format to some API? which one?  As you can see, without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's difficult to provide assistance.

Comment: A couple things from what you provided: 1) When you add the offset to the hour, you're not adjusting for time zones but rather you're picking a different point in time.  2) JavaScript already has a `getTimezoneOffset` function that does what that first block of code does, but that won't help you here.  3) The offset from UTC may be different depending on the date you apply it to, such as when summer time is in effect.  4) You may end up needing a library such as [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) or [Moment-Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), depending on your input string.

Comment: Thanks Matt Johnson. Indeed, I figured out that I need to go for an external library. I have been able to solve the problem with 'moment-timezone'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found to solve the problem.
It is based on an external library: 'moment-timezone'

```
        // Example's initial setup
        const dateFormat = require('dateformat')
        const moment = require('moment-timezone');
        const timeReceivedFrom3rdPartyAPI = "14:30" // Format "HH:mm", Paris time

        // Construct Date object with today's date and timeReceivedFrom3rdPartyAPI
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const currentDateString = dateFormat(currentDate, "yyyy-mm-dd");
        const estimatedDateTimeOfArrival = moment.tz(`${currentDateString} ${timeReceivedFrom3rdPartyAPI}`, "Europe/Paris").toDate()

        console.log(estimatedDateTimeOfArrival)
        // 08/03/2018 13:30 UTC
        // Now I have UTC Full Date corresponding to timeReceivedFrom3rdPartyAPI
```

Comment: Don't tack on the date.  You're using the current *local* date, which may or may not be the same as the current date in the given time zone.  Just let Moment do the work: `moment.tz('14:30', 'HH:mm', 'Europe/Paris')`.   Also, unless you need the output to be a `Date` object, you're better off calling `.toISOString()`, or `.utc().format()`.  (The latter would allow you to pass a format string if you want a specific format).